# How do I make my website retina display friendly?

Tags: optimization, mac, ipad

Recently the retina MacBook Pro was released at WWDC 2012. It has a resolution of 2880 by 1800. This makes websites look really bad if they haven't been optimized for the new high-res display, as [noted by Marco Arment](http://www.marco.org/2012/07/05/web-designers-need-retina). What are some thing I need to do to optimize my website for retina displays?

Comment: For one, make sure you are drawing the objects on a scale-based system (not pixel-based). It should be the same ratio for small/large browser resolutions. Images... include decent-resolution images. You could get fancy and display versions of the site based on the resolution (it can be detected using JS: http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jscreen.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to mix high resolution graphics, css and things like @font-face, obviously if you create a website specifically for retina displays it will create a lot of data to download with larger images etc, but what you can do is using CSS create optimised verstions for retina and non-retina visitors.

There are some great tutorials online including these:

- [Optimising Your Site for the New iPad Retina Display | The Mobile Web Design Blog](http://www.themobilewebdesignblog.com/2012/03/20/optimising-your-site-for-the-new-ipad-retina-display/)
- [Optimizing Graphics for Apple’s Retina Display Using the CSS Background Size](http://www.studiopress.com/design/css-background-size-graphics.htm)